# ActionScript Show buttons when I hover a certain area

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I am trying to achieve an effect in Flash. The effect in question is that when I hover a certain area I want my navigation (6 movie clips that acts as a button) to appear and disappear when I move my mouse out. The trouble is that right now I Can make then appear but I cannot click them nor mouse over them since I've put a transparent (alpha = 0 ) over them.

I'd like a solution or hint of a solution in AS2 but I am open to AS3 solutions as well.

Comment: The alpha property shouldn't influence the mouse behaviour. You are using listeners, right? Perhaps you could post the code in question, it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `myClip_mc.visible = false;`

Then use a MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER for the thing you are mousing over to show myClip_mc -- and in the function, say:

`myClip_mc.visible = true;`

Using Alpha is not the best practice in this case.

If you need a fade-in effect, that's different.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use actionscript!

```
area.onRollover = function() {
    btn._alpha = 100;
}

area.onRollOut = function() {
    btn._alpha = 0;
}
```

I've used this code and worked for something like you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

set mouseEnabled = false (and mouseChildren = false if it has children) on whatever's covering your navigation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits into your design or not, but instead of putting an invisible sprite over your navigation, make your navigation a child of that sprite.  That way you can keep your listeners on the container sprite and still be able to click the navigation elements